# Macro - Add row, auto fill text and formulas with relative OFFSSET, Sheet reference functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have very big problem and i can't find answer for it. Maybe You can halp me.

1. In Sheet "Intro" I have row (5), in wich are formulas: 
   (i) `C5(='Sheet1'!$A$1)`;
   (ii) `I5(=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1;17;1;1;))`; 
   (iii) In this row also is number of my tables line, i. e `B5(=1)`. This number "1" is also a hyperlink to Sheet1.enter code here
2. I have Macro, which every time automaticaly insert new row after last filled row, i. e. when i have filled 5 row and run my Macro, it inserts line 6. Therefore necessary to automatically fill this row with my formulas, that I mentioned above.

More specifically, the new row should be filled in like this:
When new row is 6:
(i) `C6(='Sheet2'!$A$1)`;
(ii) `I6(=OFFSET('Sheet2'!$A$1;17;1;1;))`; 
(iii) `B6(=2)`. This number "2" is also a hyperlink to Sheet2.
When new row is 7:
(i) `C7(='Sheet3'!$A$1)`;
(ii) `I7(=OFFSET('Sheet3'!$A$1;17;1;1;))`; 
(iii) `B7(=3)`. This number "3" is also a hyperlink to Sheet3.
When new row is 8:
(i) `C8(='Sheet4'!$A$1)`;
(ii) `I8(=OFFSET('Sheet4'!$A$1;17;1;1;))`; 
(iii) `B8(=4)`. This number "4" is also a hyperlink to Sheet4.

And......

Maybe You can help me?

In advance thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a macro in place, I would extend the macro with some additional functionality to take care of this.

Throug VBA it is simple to set the Formula of a cell.

```
Sub createRow()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 5
    Dim sheetOffset As Integer
    sheetOffset = -4

    FillInRow i, sheetOffset
End Sub

Sub FillInRow(i As Integer, sheetOffset As Integer)
    Sheets("Intro").Range("C" & i).Formula = "=Sheet" & CStr(i + sheetOffset) & "A1"
    Sheets("Intro").Range("I" & i).Formula = "=OFFSET(Sheet " & CStr(i + sheetOffset) & "3!$A$1;17;1;1;"
End Sub
```

You should set the offset carefully.

I could not understand what you needed in the "B" column. but seeing this example I am sure you can expand this.

If this is too vague, please say so and I can ellaborate.

Comment: Does not work for me, maybe we can contact in Skype and talk more about it?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to be contacted on Skype today.

This macro does work for me; it does a very simple job of setting the formulas in 2 cells.
Can you specify what does not work? Do you get an error? Does the macro show unexpected behaviour?

Maybe it also helps if you post your original macro.

Comment: Maybe i can send for you the document and then one more time specify what i want to do. Maybe can i send email for you?

Comment: I am seriously not posting my emailadres here. I am quite new here. If you can figure out how to send me a private message, feel free to ask that way.

However, I stronly feel that with minimal VBA skills you should understand this code and get it to work.
You obviously have a macro (so I guess you recorded it). If you post that macro, I can point out where to add more functionality.

Additionaly, find out how to debug VBA code. That will make this process much easier for you.

Comment: Ok. I have idea. I can give my email acount for you. Go to gmail.com, account name macrousing@gmail.com, pass: macro123. Here i will import my document

Comment: Now document is in macrousing@gmail.com

Comment: I have just taken a look and it is clear to me that you are too far from a working solution for help. You need someone to do the job for you.

I will not be that person for you.

Your description makes more sense to me now. However, going from where you are now to a working solution will take me a bunch of time.

I suggest you learn how to work with VBA. Then come back to this forum and ask some more precise questions.

Comment: Maybe you can give some steps what i must to do. I dont work with VBA and is very hard to do it. Please, help for lady.  It will be very nice and pleasure from you ;)

Comment: Maybe you can help me in the document only with macros in B, C and I cells. Other cells i think i can do

Comment: Hi, But I have one more problem. 
I have button, which instert date in the cell A1
I need, that in the cell a1 will be date of the time, when i pushed the button.
Now i use function =TODAY(), but this function is not suitable for me. He show actualy date every day, but not the date of the time, when i pushed the button..